# Использование постороннего сервиса с помощью CORS/AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

Есть вот такой сервис для отслеживания почтовых отправлений:
http://www.trackitonline.ru.

Можно ли каким то образом использовать данный ресурс используя кросс-доменный Ajax-запрос CORS без использования API данного сайта? API данного ресурса по словам поддержки сырое и к тому же платное.

Ну типа с сайта [http://www.мойсайт.ru](http://www.%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.ru) отправить форму/запрос на сайт http://www.trackitonline.ru.

Где найти информацию об этом? Или подскажите как это сделать.
Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61640/discussion-on-question-by------).